# @relatedToVia on an array

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

Trying to create @relatedToVia as mentioned below.

```
@NodeEntity
abstract public class Table{
@GraphId
Long id1;
@RelatedToVia(type="hasRowFields")
protected RowField[] rowFields;
```

Can we relate on an array data type?
If not, what is the other way of relating in this scenario?

Error

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException
```

Answer (score 0):

I think arrays are not supported, try `List<RowField>` but `RowField` has to be a `NodeEntity` too.